# Only load an iframe after class appears in container div (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pagespeed

I have a unique issue where I am loading a lot of iframes on a page and it significantly reduces performance.

Since they are all inside of popup modals, I want to trigger the iframe to load after someone clicks on the modal.

When the modal loads using JS, a class is added called '.in' and this data attribute is changed from true to false "aria-hidden="false".

Here is a sample of the DIV as the trigger:

```
<div id="ModalPopUp-data-integration-service" class="modal hide fade in" data-
backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
```

Here is the iframe I want to load:

```
<iframe src="http://XXXXX.com" width="100%" height="800" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Cool, I'll update that

Comment: if you are handling the click event for the popup, you can always set the src of the iframe at that time. Initially you can set the iframe to have an empty "src" or set the "src" to an empty html.

Comment: `I want to trigger the iframe to load after someone clicks on the modal` You have to better describe what behaviour you are expecting? Which click? And see @Jas comment, just set `src` attribute of iframe when needed

Comment: You can also use a `Mutation Observer` to observe changes in the DOM on an element. [Have a look at the MDN Docs on Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Jas Yes, jas that would be ideal. I am really terrible with JS so help figuring out how to write the code is what I need.

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff - see my response to Jas

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That makes sense too. I have no idea how to write that. Could you help me out?

Comment: @frameworkgeek The link that I provided has an example in the documentation. Have a look, do some testing.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am trying my darnedist to understand this, but I think it's way over my head. I get what what the concept is, but I am not a javascript expert by any means. If I knew how to find a working example that's relevant to my scenario, I could probably figure out how to match up the options. I just don't know how to identify that.

Comment: If you provide a MCVE, it would be fixed quickly. Is the iFrame inside modal? Can you share more context regarding your HTML markup? And what modal are you talking about? Any plugin? Doesn't it fire any event on shown? Etc... Your question is just missing **some context**. Mutation Observer could be used in some way for sure but it would be like bringing gun to pillow fight...

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not even cool enough to know what MCVE is :/ BUT I think you are asking for the website...http://www.whatcounts.com/services-2/

Once loaded (takes forever) you will see tiles using isotope. When you click one, they fire a modal that is a Pagelines plugin. This writes in the above class and data attribute. Unfortunately, I have not been able to load jquery inside the page without breaking the Pagelines frontend drag and drop UI. Inside the modal there is the iframe with a form.

Comment: @frameworkgeek Sorry [MCVE javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Second link on google :) But i'll look at your site and let you know. And you are already including jQuery, so why not using it? And btw see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You should had asked question regarding your jQuery issue instead

Comment: @A.Wolff when I try to use it, it breaks the ui - something with being logged in and using the editor... I wish I could tell you more. Forgive me for not enough context, will do better next time!

Comment: @frameworkgeek np, like said i'll check your site

Answer (score 2):

This is what you could use. Don't set `src` attribute by default for iframe, but e.g `data-src` one:

```
<iframe data-src="http://XXXXX.com" width="100%" height="800" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
```

Then once needed, set the relevant `src` attribute depending `data` one. You could use `transitionend` event for that:

```
document.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  var iframe = e.target.id === "ModalPopUp-third-party-content" && e.target.querySelector('iframe');
  if (iframe && !iframe.src) {
    iframe.src = iframe.dataset.src;
  }
}, false);
```

That's said, you'd have better to use relevant modal event onshown, check doc. BUT your site is really really buggy and gives headhache to debug. I really don't want to be rude. It would need serious refactorization like said in other answer.

I'm even not sure why you use iframes when i guess a single form, setting on each opening event modal relevant info would be enough.

Comment: Upped `transitionend` nice.

Comment: This is working on most of the popups, but not all. Any suggestions?